# Android ViewPager app hangs when debugging

Tags: android, debugging, android-viewpager

I have a problem to debug an app implementing the ViewPager example from  [ViewPager Class Overview](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html).
Debugger/IDE:
IntelliJ IDEA 13 132.839

Devices: 
-Samsung Galaxy S2
-Virtual Device

When i launch the app it hangs at this line:

```
mTabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(this, mViewPager);
```

(There is no breakpoint)

On the device i see a black screen. If i disconnect the debugger, the app will proceed.
If i start the appliaction without debugger, it will run without any problems.

Can anybody confirm this problem? 
How can i find out, if this is a problem debugging a ViewPager App in general or if it is a aproblem with my debugger?

The main problem is, that i want to debug some lines of code after new `TabsAdapter()`...

Thanks
Andreas